Complexity of a multi-column b-tree index
According to one of Sebastian Brestin's posts, a multi-column b-tree index will look like something below.  It seems that more columns doesn't create a deeper b-tree. So if a single-column (n entries) b-tree index has a search/insert/update complexity: O(log(n)) and space complexity: O(n),  does a m-column (n entries) b-tree index also have a search/insert/update complexity: O(log(m*n)) and space complexity: O(m*n)?

PS: If database vendors matter, I would like to know about PostgreSQL.

Yes, if you have a composite key, where each member is of the same data type (uses the same amount of space), then you would consider that the space used for one (composite) key is O(), and the key comparisons have a time complexity of O() in the worst case.
If  is a constant, then you have the usual time complexity of O(log) and space complexity O(). For dynamically determined  (but of course, fixed for a given B-tree) you are correct that you can replace  by  in those expressions: O(log) and O().

Would you mind to explain why the time complexity is O(logn) if m is constant?

Constant coefficients do not influence time complexity. O(2n) = O(n) = 0(1000n)
